# VBA, coding a dynamic range (column) for sorting data

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, range

I am a bit of a rookie in vba and I am stuck on something which should be relatively easy:
I have a marco specifying the column number from the headers names:

```
Dim onomata As Integer
'find column named Name of ship
Set acell = rows(1).Find(What:="Name of ship", LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not acell Is Nothing Then
    onomata = acell.Column
End If
```

Now I want to sort my data based on this column:

```
Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( *this is where I want to introduce the column* ), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:AR100000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

However, my variable is integer while the command requests a range value. Can anyone help me in how to code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stating `ActiveSheet` is enough, there's no meaning to using `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`.

Use the code below to sort according to the numeric result you got for `onomata`.

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Columns(onomata), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
End With
```

Comment: What if I want to sort by more than 1 criterion? like first sort by column A and then by column B???

Comment: @e-gnacio sounds like a great new SO post, you should open a new one, this will allow other users (and me) to assist you

Answer (score 1):

You only need this...

```
Dim acell As Range

'find column named Name of ship
Set acell = Rows(1).Find(What:="Name of ship", LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not acell Is Nothing Then        
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Sort key1:=acell.Offset(1, 0), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End If
```

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes that doesn't make any sense. I didn't look at it closely and copied OP's code. Lol  Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= ActiveSheet.Cells(onomata).EntireColumn
```